# State and input simultaneous estimation

Tags: estimation, references, nonlinear, state-space-models

I have a discrete nonlinear state space model :
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
x_k & = f(x_{k-1},u_{k-1},\theta)+q_{k-1}\\
y_k & = f(x_k,\theta)+r_k
\end{aligned} 
\end{equation}

$x_{k-1} \in R^{n_x}$ is the state of the dynamic system at discrete time $k$, $f: R^{n_x} \times R^{n_u} \rightarrow R^{n_x}$ and $h:R^{n_x} \rightarrow R^{n_z}$ are some known function; $u_{k-1} \in R^{n_u}$ some unknown input, $y_k \in R^{n_z}$ is the measurement, $q_{k-1}$ and $r_k$ are independent process and measurement Gaussian noise sequences with zero means and covariances $Q_{k-1}$ and $R_k$ respectively.

My purpose is to estimate the State and input simultaneous from real measurement data $z_k$, that best fit the model to the data.

I want some advice about good references (book, paper or any reliable document) that handle the state and input simultaneous estimation for kind of the model described above.